# Unable to pass the argv to a function called inside main

Tags: c++

I am a beginner to coding and below is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int Function_Block(argc,argv);
//Other operations
```

The Function_Block is being defined like this:

```
int Function_Block(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    if(strcmp("1",argv[1])==0) {
        set_Flag = 1;
    }
    //Other Operations and return 0
```

I am getting an error that states

```
error C2078: too many initializers
```

and

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char **' to 'int'
```

I checked the MSDN website but i did not really follow its description on passing the argv parameters.
Any information to debug or fix this would be helpful.

Comment: I have already declared the function in the the header file for main... as    int Function_Block(int argc,char* argv[]);

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to call the function inside `main`? If you are, you should do something like

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   int a = Function_Block(argc,argv);
//Other operations
```

Where `a` will store the integer returned by your function. Right now, you seem to be declaring the function *inside* `main`, which is not correct.

Comment: Thank you that fixed that error but now i seem to be getting a new linking error:
     error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: You seem to have defined something more than once - maybe once in the header and once more in the driver file. But it is really hard to say exactly what is wrong, given the little information. Can you post some more code? Edit your question, perhaps?